# Example: traceless C*-algebra universally generated by projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Does someone have an example of

1. a non-zero C*-algebra which is
2. universally generated by
3. finitely many projections (not all commuting) together with a unit and plus
4. necessarily satisfying some additional relations such that
5. there remain no traces?

In other words, is there a non-zero quotient
$$C^*(Z/2*\ldots*Z/2)\to B\to 0$$
which carries no traces?
So basically the question is about the representation theory of $C^*(Z/2*\ldots*Z/2)$.

Or more generally, what classes of groups are there with some traceless quotients?

**EDIT:**
Question got answered on mathoverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/a/409043/45494

Comment: What do you mean "plus necessarily some additional relations"?

Comment: Without additional relations this defines the full group algebra $C^*(Z/2*…*Z/2)$ which carries a trace. However any other such algebra is a quotient thereof. Thus imposing additional relations just meant quotients $C^*(Z/2*…*Z/2)\to Q\to 0$. Such must not come from group algebras themselves in order for them to be traceless.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification:)

Comment: Thanks for asking :)